# private jet based of an sr 71

Tags: supersonic, sr-71, private-jets, modifications

could a private jet be based of an SR 71 blackbird. By this I mean similar styling and shape. Would this be a good basis to make a private jet super sonic (disregarding sonic boom). What would the major adjustments be for the SR 71 to be a private jet?

By this I mean: to make a cabin of decent size; take off and land at non military airports; standalone (not needing refuelling etc) and yet supersonic travel.

Comment: A private jet _to do what_ supersonically? If you want something that can carry cameras higher and faster than your enemy's air defence systems can intercept, the SR-71 could be a reasonable place to start. If you want something to get your CEO to their next meeting on time, it'd be a pretty terrible place to start.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I have specified in the question.

Comment: It would be better a lot cheaper to buy a demilitarized fighter and turn that into a business jet, the SR71 was designed very mission specific, not even close to this kind of use.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, a private jet could be based on the design of the SR-71, but there would have to be a market for it.

Considering how expensive it would be to produce, operate, and maintain, no one would want to buy it, so it will never happen.